# how to import vagrant without going through 'vagrant add box'

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the vagrant 'virtualbox' virtual machine, however I can no longer access vagrant with another pc to retrieve my information contained in the virtual machine.

'ubuntu/focus'

how can I proceed?

Comment: you need the files stored in the `.vagrant` folder of your project directory (where you have the Vagrantfile)

Comment: okay, i will check it

Comment: @FredericHenri thank you. its okay. but how can I retrieve all information in them

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag:  GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project directory (the one where you have the `Vagrantfile`) vagrant will create . `.vagrant` folder. The content of this folder has the Virtalbox vm information

for example:

```
ls -all .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  11 fhenri  staff   352 Aug 28 22:20 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 fhenri  staff    96 Aug 27 22:38 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    40 Aug 28 22:20 action_provision
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    10 Aug 28 22:18 action_set_name
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff   148 Sep  6 09:42 box_meta
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff     3 Aug 28 22:18 creator_uid
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    36 Aug 28 22:18 id
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    32 Aug 28 22:18 index_uuid
-rw-------   1 fhenri  staff  1679 Aug 28 22:18 private_key
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff   316 Sep  6 10:18 synced_folders
-rw-r--r--   1 fhenri  staff    63 Aug 28 22:18 vagrant_cwd
```

the name of the vagrant machine is default and provider is virtual box in this case.

If you copy the virtual box VM into another PC, you also need to copy this folder or need to recreate it. It contains the id of virtual box VM which helps vagrant to map and link with the VM.